# function pointer and function is incompatible because of arguments

Tags: c, arguments, function-pointers, void-pointers, incompatibility

I have read the book *Understanding and Using C Pointers* and try to compile the code below. But after compiling I got the warning: **assignment from incompatible pointer type**.

I have checked the code and find out the function pointer `fptrSet` and function `ShapeSetX` is incompatible because the first argument of fptrSet is `void *` and function ShapeSetX is `Shape *`.

How can I fix this?
Thanks!

```
typedef void (*fptrSet)(void*, int);
typedef int  (*fptrGet)(void*);
typedef void (*fptrDisplay)();    

typedef struct _vfunc
{
    fptrSet     setX;
    fptrGet     getX;
    fptrSet     setY;
    fptrGet     getY;
    fptrDisplay display;    
} vFunc;    

typedef struct _shape
{
    vFunc function;
    int x;
    int y;
} Shape;

void displayShape(){
    printf("Shape\n");
}
void ShapeSetX(Shape *shape, int x){
    shape->x = x;
}
void ShapeSetY(Shape *shape, int y){
    shape->y = y;
}
int ShapeGetX(Shape *shape){
    return shape->x;
}
int ShapeGetY(Shape *shape){
    return shape->y;
}    

Shape *newShape()
{
    Shape *shape = (Shape *)malloc(sizeof(Shape));
    shape->x = 10;
    shape->y = 10;
    shape->function.setX = ShapeSetX;
    shape->function.getX = ShapeGetX;
    shape->function.setY = ShapeSetY;
    shape->function.getY = ShapeGetY;
    shape->function.display = displayShape;
    return shape;
}
```

Comment: I think you can also change the `typedef void (*fptrSet)(void*, int)` to `typedef void (*fptrSet)(Shape*, int)` and the same for `fptrGet`.

Comment: @KevinWallis I think he wants something like virtual table from C++, so because there are no inheritance in C, he has to use `void` to allow "derived" struct from `Shape`

Comment: @KevinWallis @Garf365 is right, as you see this code is try to simulate the vtable from C++, so the the argument must be `void *`

Comment: Also : take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to respect pointer definition: pointer need that first parameter is a pointer to void, so your function implementation should have first parameter as void:

```
void ShapeSetX(void *void_shape, int x){
    Shape *shape = (Shape*) void_shape;
    shape->x = x;
}
void ShapeSetY(void *void_shape, int y){
    Shape *shape = (Shape*) void_shape;
    shape->y = y;
}
int ShapeGetX(void *void_shape){
    Shape *shape = (Shape*) void_shape;
    return shape->x;
}
int ShapeGetY(void *void_shape){
    Shape *shape = (Shape*) void_shape;
    return shape->y;
}
```

Comment: @Garf365 Thanks for you answer and you got what I want. I try to use the code to simulate the 'ploymorphism' from OOP. Really thank you !

Comment: @FatMouse I think you have also to pass by a base structure, common on each instance (to access safetly to vtable). And also, in C++, vtable are static, you only store pointer to vtable in your instance. I try something to implements vtable here : http://ideone.com/P8dk6g any comments will be appreciate ;)

Answer (score 1):

I was going to say "Why don't you replace `void` with `Shape` then?", until I realised that `Shape` hadn't been defined yet - nor could you swap the two definitions, because `Shape` needs `vFunc` which needs the `typedef`s.

So, do this:

```
typedef struct _shape Shape; // Define _shape and Shape later

typedef void (*fptrSet)(Shape*, int);
typedef int  (*fptrGet)(Shape*);
typedef void (*fptrDisplay)();
```

If your compiler doesn't like that, you may need to change it to:

```
typedef struct _shape; // Define _shape later

typedef void (*fptrSet)(struct _shape*, int);
typedef int  (*fptrGet)(struct _shape*);
typedef void (*fptrDisplay)();
```

Comment: With this solution, you can use `_vfunc` with other structure than `Shape`. I think OP wants a solution to have "inheritance" solution in C

Comment: For example with a function `int getXOfInstance(void * instance, vFunc * vfunc) { return vfund->getX(instance);}`

Comment: @Garf I thought of that - but with names like `set/get' 'X/y` and `Display` it all sounded rather "Shape-y"

Comment: It's not necessarily a Shape, it can be anything which have X, Y properties